# How can I determine the equation for the output voltage?

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor

[image]

This is circuit is proposed for a thermomether based on the TSP102 sensor (linear PTC). How can I determine the equation for the output voltage? My main question is about the op amp. I know that two voltages dividers are the inputs of the op amp. What would the equation be for the op amp output?

Comment: Have you done the current calculations yet?

Comment: Yes, I have them.

Comment: Then calculate Vo/Vin and...done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to simplify the problem is to use the Thevenin equivalent circuits for those voltage dividers you have there. That is, you could draw the circuit in this manner:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5fB74.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here $$V_{th1}=\frac{R_1}{R_{sensor}+R_1}V_{cc}$$ 
\$R_1\$ is just your 680 ohm resistor in series with your 500 ohm potentiometer. \$V_{cc}\$ is the supply voltage.

Your \$R_{th1}\$ is simply:
$$R_{th1}=R_1||R_{sensor} $$

The same procedure is done for \$V_{th2}\$ and \$R_{th2}\$.

You should get \$ V_{th2}=\frac{V_{cc}}{2}\$ and \$R_{th2}=\frac{R}{2}\$. Where \$R=1.2k\Omega\$.

Now, you can use \$V^-=V^+\$ and start your opamp analysis. In the end, you should obtain the equation for the opamp as a differential amplifier. I'll let you do the math, but your final solution for \$V_{out}\$ should be (if I didn't mess up somewhere):

$$ V_{out}=V_{th2}-\frac{R_f}{R_{th1}}(V_{th1}-V_{th2})$$

Where \$R_f\$ is your \$5k\Omega\$ feedback potentiometer.